# Function for Iteration over tuples

Tags: python, tuples, python-itertools

I have the following problem:
I want to iterate over a given list and return the minimum of the sum of all possible cartesian products:

```
from itertools import product

z = ((1, 2),(2, 3))

def zmin(tup):
    return min(sum(a*a for a in s) for s in product(tup))

zmin(z) --> ERROR MESSAGE
```

The correct answer should be like that:

```
1*1 + 2*2 =  5
1*1 + 3*3 = 10
2*2 + 2*2 =  8
2*2 + 3*3 = 13
```

So that the return value of zmin(z) = 5

Do you know what am i doing wrong?
Also is there an efficient way with bumpy or something similar?

Comment: Please always include the error message. It probably tells you exactly what is wrong with your code: That `product` requires at least two arguments, and you only pass one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an soloution myself:
I added `*args` for return value:

```
def zmin(tup):
    return min(sum(a*a for a in s) for s in product(*tup))
```